# Magento: make PDO results into a Varien Object

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, magento, pdo

I have a stored procedure that I call upon using 'core_read' and query method. The results are then gathered using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).

The data comes out perfectly. I can do a foreach on the array, and access data by array keys ($row['name']).

I would like to convert the associative array into a Varien_Object, so I could access the data using $row->getName() notation... Keeping it in Magento style... How would I perform such a conversion, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions, and I think it would have worked if I had one line coming back from the stored procedure. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
   $orders[] = new Varien_Object($row);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass your array to the constructor of Varien_Object

```
$object = new Varien_Object($array);
```

See the code for the constructor in lib/varien/object

Answer (score 3):

I think you just can use:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $object = new Varien_Object();
    $object->setData($row);
}
```